# When the keyboard is opened on any page, such an error appears, can you help? Thnks (It gives the same error even if it is opened with a textfield)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

// >Thread 1: "Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds row (7) when there are only 0 rows in section 0. Table view: <UITableView: 0x149845800; frame = (0 0; 390 844); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002617b70>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003df38c0; name = tableBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000028fdf20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {390, 50}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <Mobilyum.AnaViewController: 0x14b04a400>>"

````
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

class MesajYazViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var gonderButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mesajTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mesajAlaniView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mesajTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firmaNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var firmaImageView: UIImageView!
    
    var firma: Firmalar?
    var gecerliKullanici: Firmalar?
    var item: Item?
    
    var mesaj = [Mesaj]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        


        let contentView = UIView()
         contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
         
         mesajTextField.leftView = contentView
         mesajTextField.leftViewMode = .always
         mesajTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        
        mesajTableView.dataSource = self
        mesajTableView.delegate = self
        
        mesajTableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        mesajTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
     
        
      



        
        gecerliKullaniciyiGetir()

        fetchMessages()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
        
    }

   

   

    
     func gecerliKullaniciyiGetir(){
        
         UserService.currentFetchUser { firma in
             self.gecerliKullanici = firma
         }
    }
       
    
    func fetchMessages(){
        MessageService.fetchMessages(firma: firma, item: item) { messages in
                self.mesaj = messages

            self.mesajTableView.reloadData()
            if self.mesaj.isEmpty == false{
                self.mesajTableView.scrollToRow(at: [0, self.mesaj.count-1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }
        }
       
        
       
    }
    
    @IBAction func gonderButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

       
        if mesajTextField.text != "" {
            MessageService.uploadMessage(message: mesajTextField.text ?? "", toFirma: firma, item: item) { error in
                if let error = error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                self.mesajTextField.text = ""
            }
        }
        }
    }
    



extension MesajYazViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mesaj.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MesajYazTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MesajYazTableViewCell
        
        cell.mesaj = mesaj[indexPath.row]
        cell.mesaj?.firma = firma
        cell.mesaj?.item = item
        
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        mesajTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
    
    
}


```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBVK0.jpg
````

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlqKQ.png)

Comment: The error explains itself you are trying to scroll to specific cell when the keyboard appears i can't see that line of code in the code that you are sharing

Comment: I added the missing code part Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in this line you are scrolling to the cell when the messaj is empty

```
self.mesajTableView.scrollToRow(at: [0, self.mesaj.count-1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

but i see you added an if condition so i think it might be asynchronous issue, this function MessageService.fetchMessages maybe running on a different queue so run your closure inside main queue like this and see if it works

```
func fetchMessages(){
    MessageService.fetchMessages(firma: firma, item: item) { messages in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.mesaj = messages
            
            self.mesajTableView.reloadData()
            if self.mesaj.isEmpty == false{
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    self.mesajTableView.scrollToRow(at: [0, self.mesaj.count-1], at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i added this line DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter just to make sure the cell is visible before scrolling

Comment: ahmed unfortunately not solved, then i realized that,
I'm facing the same problem in whichever page I open the keyboard, what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: It gives the same error even if it is opened with a textfield Ahmed

Comment: This code you shared is working fine. try to comment the scrolling line [self.mesajTableView.scrollToRow(at: [0, self.mesaj.count-1], at: .bottom, animated: true)] and see if the issue is fixed or not. if not so whatever causing the problem is not presented in the code above. if you are listening on the keyboard shows or hides notification share that code as well

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, Resolved by uninstalling notification observer, Selamun Aleykum 

Comment: YAY :D  thanks to you i learn too from answering questions, Aleykum Selam :D

Comment: Super i am trying to learn 